# CFML / Fusebox: An Error of type "fusebox.badGrammar.unexpectedAttributes" has occured

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, fusebox

I have a problem with a 10 year old ColdFusion / Fusebox application running on a ColdFusion 8 Server. This is the complete error message:

---

```
An Error of type "fusebox.badGrammar.unexpectedAttributes" has occured

Unexpected attributes

Unexpected attributes were found in a "include" verb in fuseaction [model_login_request].
```

---

[...] is variable, that means that this kind of error occurs more often, but in different sections. Sometimes model login, or model user, or controller.

The application runs normal, then this error occurs from one second to another, without any changes in the program code.

The recovery is simple, but very crazy. I download the model or controller directory, dependent on where the error occurred. Then I upload the directory again 1:1 without any changes. I only delete the content in the `"parsed"` directory and everything begins working again.

The error only occurs in the live environment, never had it in the development environment. The code on both is the same. The only difference is, that the live environment has more data in the database and the usage is more intense. The error has been occurring more frequently in the last weeks.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem could be located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the fusebox.xml file in both live and development and see if "mode" is set accordingly. In the live environment, it should have a value of "production"

With mode="production", the files generated in the parsed directory are only done once, while in other modes they might be regenerated on every request. In a high-load environment, this can lead to fusebox regenerating those files while they are in use by other requests and can cause this type of error.

Comment: The application was in development mode. The problem didnt come back since i changed the mode. Thank you for your answer!